# Conditional Probability going wrong

Tags: probability

**The question**

In basketball, when Monica takes her first free throw, she has a 50% chance of scoring. If she takes an additional throw, she has a 75% chance of scoring on this throw if she scored on the immediately previous throw, but only a 25% chance of scoring on this throw if she didn't score on the immediately previous throw. Suppose she has to take a set of three free throws in a row, and she doesn't score on the first one. What is the probability that she scores at least once on one of the subsequent two throws?

**My attempt -**

We can find the probability of not scoring and then subtract it from 1.

**P**(atleast 1 score)= 1 - **P**(no score)

Now as per question,

> only a 25% chance of scoring on this throw if she didn't score on the immediately previous throw.

and

> she doesn't score on the first one.

**P**(no score) = (1/4)*(1/4) = 1/16

**P**(atleast 1 score)= 1 - 1/16 = 1/15

When I checked the answer they used **3/4** instead of **1/4**.

**My issue -**

Why did they take 3/4 when it clearly says the chance of *making the shot is 25% **if she doesn't score in previous one***. So it has to be 25% not 75%.

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said she has only a 25% chance of scoring on the second throw if she didn't score on the immediately previous throw.  This means she has a 75% chance of not scoring on the second throw if she didn't score on the immediately previous throw.  Thus (3/4) is correct, since you are computing the chance that she fails both.

I'd check your number for her odds on the first throw as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a miss on the first throw, there are only 4 combinations: miss/hit in 2nd and miss/hit in 3rd, so you get

- MM $\to 3/4 \times 3/4$
- MH $\to 3/4 \times 1/4$
- HM $\to 1/4 \times 1/4$
- HH $\to 1/4 \times 3/4$

Can you finish this?